# Java ArrayList copy without creating a new array

Tags: java, memory, collections, arraylist, copy

I have a List implementation (not mine) with an underlying array.

The implementation does not give access to the array directly, but only through the LIST INTERFACE methods that are implemented (just as an ArrayList implementation)

At some point, i will not able to work with this list (because of its implementation), but i will need to access (READ only) the data (underlying array).

Is there a way this can be achieved? Can a new ArrayList be created using the underlying array of the old one, **without the creation of an ARRAY COPY**?

Comment: It's now entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve. A view on an existing collection? What would you want to happen if you added entries onto the original collection? Or onto the new one? Please clarify.

Comment: Changes on the original list array will "write through" to the cloned list. The objective is to have a new list not bound to the original list implementation, but without the need to replicate the huge array of elements...

Comment: Well how do you expect them to stay independent without copying? You should edit your question to be a lot clearer about what you want.

Comment: I understand your point. They will share the same array. Why is that such a big problem? Changes to one collection reflect to the other...

Comment: So you *do* just want a view? In what way do you want it to be "not bound to the original list implementation"? I don't know how many different ways I can say "this question isn't clear enough"...

Comment: Jon, i can't use the original List because of the implementation of that list! It's a list that represents a QUERY result set, bound to a database connection, and when i access the list, there are many implications, such as access to the database, not to mention that i cannot access any methods after the query is closed! I don't need to replicate the already loaded data array, i just need to bound it to another list implementation (ArrayList). How can i make my question any clearer? Is it nonsense?? if it is, i will vote to close this one myself!

Comment: But is there even an array underlying that list? And can you get at it? Do you need to be able to add items to the result? Might Arrays.asList be enough for you? You *still* haven't provided nearly enough information, and you should put the extra information into the question instead of in comments.

Comment: Yes, there is an underlying array. No, i cannot access the array. If i had access, Arrays.asList() would be right on the money! I only have the List Interface methods available in the implementation...

Comment: I edited the question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Well if nothing gives access to the array, then the simple answer is no... There's nothing in the list interface to help you. Or at least, some of the methods *might* be useful to you, but we don't know what it is about the existing implementation which would cause problems.

Comment: As i said, i cannot access the list after the the query that is bound to it is CLOSED. Surely when implementing, no one thought that the collection would be accessed after the query is closed, but i found it very useful, if not vital for certain tasks (ex: reports can't use several of these query-lists at the same time if the query is opened, and cannot access ANY of them if the query is closed!). Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to have a new array to back the `ArrayList` anyway - so why is it a problem that it calls `c.toArray()`? The only inefficiency would be if it ends up in the branch calling `Arrays.copyOf`.

Comment: Please rephrase your answer so i can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList(int) also creates an array

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
   ...
   this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

but ArrayList(Collection) uses fast copying

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```